# Ajax send google chart data work in Visual Studio, but not working outside or on server

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, ajax, ashx

My project right now has one html, one ashx and one js file, it has a google pie chart that receive data from Maria DB via ADO.Net method, when I open the html in Visual Studio the chart works fine, but when I try to open the html outside of Visual Studio or put it on server it does not work, it return error 404 as if Ajax couldn't find the ashx file despite I place it in exact location as the html file.

I have try to copy the file into my local machine IIS location, but doing this and open the html I get error 405 method not allowed instead of 404

Can anyone help?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'game2019.ashx',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (result) {

        $(function () {

            var v = new Array();

            v.push(['name', 'ratio']);

            $.each(result, function (i, item) {

                v.push(new Array(item.name, parseFloat(item.ratio)));

            });

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(v);


            var options = {
                title: 'No Title',
                pieHole: 0.2,
                'width': 'auto',
                'height': '300',
                textStyle: {
                    color: '#fff',                      
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontName: 'Microsoft JhengHei',     
                    bold: false,
                    italic: false
                },
                titleTextStyle: {
                    color: '#fff',                      
                    fontSize: 22,
                    fontName: 'Microsoft JhengHei',     
                    bold: false,
                    italic: false
                }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('ten-chart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);



        })

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR.status);
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```